# box2d body velocity is unexpectedly extremely high

Tags: box2d, velocity

I am building a simple 2d game where a snake can spit fireballs at player and he has to avoid those. Player moves around and the snake is static, but it rotates around its center to follow player's movement.

At some point snake spits a fireball which is a dynamic body with CircleShape sensor fixture attached. 
Fireball is supposed to move linearly at 2 units per sec speed. Since direction of attack is always different I set x and y components of the velocity separately, based on the rotation angle:

```
fireball_velocity.x = Snake.FIREBALL_VELOCITY * MathUtils.cos(angle);
fireball_velocity.y = Snake.FIREBALL_VELOCITY * MathUtils.sin(angle);
```

Then resulting velocity is set to newly created fireball body as linear velocity:

```
body.setLinearVelocity(fireball_velocity);
```

After that fireball body is not affected by any forces or impulses (gravity scale for it is set to 0)

50% of the time (or maybe more) this works  just fine, but sometimes (also quite often) fireball velocity is extremely high, so high that it even can get through player body without collison being detected!

I have checked fireball_velocity.x and fireball_velocity.y with debugger - they are always between -2.00f and 2.00f and at those times when fireball speed goes high also. So it seems that even though provided linear velocity value is always small, sometimes box2d engine processes this incorrectly...

I also tried to make fireball radius bigger just in case it was to small to calculate or smth, but it did not matter.

Box2d coordinates are kept between 0 and 10 units as advised in the manual.

What can cause this problem?

Comment: just a guess: do you mix up degrees and radians?

Comment: Nope, I'm using radians everywhere and that part actually works correctly - fireball always flies in the right direction. But sometimes with extreme velocity for some reason. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: well, a guess is a guess :)

Comment: Are you pooling the fireballs/box2d bodies?

Comment: No, currently I create a new fireball body everytime and then destroy it when fireball hits smth.

Comment: What port of Box2D are you using? Is the fireball body able to collide with the snake body as it is being launched? So you mean that the value of Snake.FIREBALL_VELOCITY is 2? And you're saying that too-high  speed is between -2 and 2? Wouldn't that mean it's actually going slower than what you wanted? How about using GetLinearVelocity to check the velocity instead of those .x and .y properties of whatever fireball_velocity is? Is the too-high speed always the same speed? Does it occur at any angle, or more common at some angles?

Comment: I use LibGDX engine and Box2D that comes with it  No, fireball body and the snake body cannot collide (I even turned snake body off to be sure of that)  Yes, Snake.FIREBALL_VELOCITY is a constant value of 2. its projections to x and y are always between -2 and 2, and resulting vector is 2. I have followed your advice and checked GetLinearVelocity of a flying fireball - its velocity always starts correctly at 2, but then sometimes accelerates greatly to 20-40 units.  So I guess my question turns out to be: why can velocity set with setLinearVelocity accelerate?

Comment: I did not notice particular angle to be more common for the problem

Comment: The only way a body can change speed/direction is by ApplyForce, ApplyImpulse, SetLinearVelocity, gravity, or responding to a collision with something. So you mean it initially starts off at the correct speed and then gets faster after launch? Does it do that suddenly, or gradually?

Comment: oh, and due to joint constraints.

Comment: Gradually, but very quickly. I have somewhat localized the issue now. I have other bodies (blocks) in the game which are kinematic bodies. Those move around with their velocity set by setLinearVelocity also, and they pass the place where fireball is to be created. So the issue seems to happen, if fireball body is created in the area where block body was moving. However debug renderer clearly shows that at the time of fireball creation block body is not there. I don't use setTransform for any bodies (I have read somewhere that can cause world inconsistency).

Comment: When I remove these block bodies from the game fireballs velocity is always correct.  Can block bodies leave some kind of "ghost" information about their position in the world?

Comment: If the problem goes away when you remove those block bodies, then I would have to assume the fireball is colliding with them somehow. It seems very odd that the direction of the fireball would not change though. You can easily set the filter bits to make them ignore each other. No, there is no residual 'ghost' of bodies that remains (unless of course, they are actually edges with ghost vertices). It kinda sounds like maybe your debug draw is not so reliable...

Comment: Yes, I guess I'll have to go with some workaround for now...  Thank you for all your advice!